# Não consigo checar se um array é vazio ou null

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso exibir uma mensagem sempre que o meu array for vazio ou null, porém não estou conseguindo. Chamo a função JS no PHP, passando um array com json_encode. Funciona perfeitamente, mas não checa se o array for vazio.

arquivo php:

```
$nGals = $conexao->consultarDados("select gal from portfolio where theme = '{$tem}' group by gal");

    $galArr = array();

    foreach($nGals as $rows){
        array_push($galArr, $rows);
    }

    $countArr = count($galArr);

    $x = 1;
    while($x <= $countArr){

        $parametroGal = array();

        $galeria = $conexao->consultarDados("select * from portfolio where gal = '{$x}' and theme = '{$tem}' limit 4");
        foreach($galeria as $rows){
            array_push($parametroGal, $rows['nome']);
        }

        $jsonGal = json_encode($parametroGal);

        echo "galerias(".$jsonGal.",".$x.");"; //passo o array aqui
        $x++;
    }
```

A função está em um arquivo JS separado:

```
function galerias(query,x){

    var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
    var theme = location.search.split("?tem=")[1];

    //verifica se ha imagens na determinada galeria
    //porem o if nao funciona, apenas o else funciona quando o array nao e vazio
    if(!query || query.length == 0 || query == null){
        imgs.innerHTML = "<h4>Ainda não ha galerias nesta seção.</h4>";
    }else{

    imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

    for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
        imgs.innerHTML += '<img src="img/'+query[i]+'" class="imgs-galeria""/>';
    }

    imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.php?gal="+x+"=&oth="+theme+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
    }
    console.log(query.length);
}
```

Comment: Esse código está assim no PHP? com JS e PHP misturado?

Comment: Também não entendi

Comment: @Sergio Editei a pergunta para ficar mais facil de compreender.

Comment: @anuseranother ok, assim faz mais sentido. E onde está o código do JSONP?

Comment: não é só colocar um `if (!query) return;` no js? ou da erro no json_encode?

Comment: @Sergio não fiz um codigo em json, apenas converti o array em php para json, ja foi o bastante para a situação, funciona perfeitamente, so a verificação que não...

Comment: @MaiconCarraro então cara, não da erro direto mas não funciona do mesmo jeito que está agora.

Comment: @anuseranother ok então precisas de usar o JSON.parse não? o que te dá `console.log(typeof query, typeof x);`?

Comment: @Sergio nas galerias que possuem imagens no array, me retorna "object", "number", nas que possuem o array vazio nao me retorna nada.

Comment: @anuseranother como aparece esta linha `echo "galerias(".$jsonGal.",".$x.");"; //passo o array aqui` no HTML?

Comment: @Sergio aonde possuo galeria: `galerias(["foto1_1.jpg","foto1_2.jpg","foto1_3.jpg","foto1_4.jpg"],1);`, aonde não possuo a linha nem aparece. a tag <script> fica sem conteudo

Comment: @anuseranother ok, e nessas que dá vazio o que dá `echo $countArr;` no PHP __antes__ do `while`? acho que ele nem está a entrar no `while` no PHP...

Comment: @Sergio não está, como uso apenas para contar o numero de galerias, preciso deixar ele fora para servir de referencia ao contador do while. O echo me retorna 0 e um var_dump me retorna int(0);

Comment: @anuseranother então antes do while devias ter algo como `if ($countArr == 0) echo "galerias([], 0);"; die();` não?

Comment: **Sergio** não, pois há uma `QUERY` no meio do `WHILE`

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho mas esse while nunca é corrido se o `$countArr` dá zero

Comment: Não tem problema **Sergio**, se não é corrido, o `JS` não precisa de alteração...mas se `countArr` ele PODE haver resultado pela `query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como referiste [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71560/n%C3%A3o-consigo-checar-se-um-array-%C3%A9-vazio-ou-null/71567#comment146704_71560) `$countArr` dá zero quando não há galerias -  *"O echo me retorna `0` e um var_dump me retorna `int(0)`"*. Isso quer dizer que o `while` nunca é corrido e que

```
echo "galerias(".$jsonGal.",".$x.");"; //passo o array aqui
```

nunca é corrido.

Então sugiro que cries uma alternativa no código para esses casos... algo como:

```
if ($countArr == 0) echo "galerias([], 0);"; 
else while($x <= $countArr){ // fazer o while
```

Para fazer o echo de conteudo vazio.

Comment: Só resolveria a primeira parte do problema. Dentro do `while`, também pode haver a possibilidade de `parametroGal` nunca ser preenchido.

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho como assim "dentro do while"? esse while nunca acontece no caso em que `$countArr` é `0`.

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado Sérgio, foi a resposta mais eficaz e que identificou o meu problema. Agradeço ao Sérgio e a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente seu `json_encode` está retornando `[]`, como você pode ver aqui: https://ideone.com/BO6SsT

Faz uma verificação no javascript:

```
if (query == '[]') 
    imgs.innerHTML = "<h4>Ainda não ha galerias nesta seção.</h4>";
```

Se estiver utilizando o jQuery existe o `jQuery.isEmptyObject`

```js
window.onload = function () {

var json = {};

if ($.isEmptyObject(json))
  alert('vazio');
  
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ainda nada... como se ignorasse o if completamente

Comment: @anuseranother se você colocar um `console.log(query)` aparece o que no console?

Comment: Aparece o meu json aonde o array há valores, aonde não há não aparece nada.

Comment: @anuseranother coloquei uma outra alternativa

Comment: Vou ficar com a resposta do Sergio pois foi a que melhor encaixou para mim, mas agradeço pela ajuda !